# Are there any additional considerations to make when designing a site structure if you plan to use persistent connection technologies?

Tags: c#, websites, project-structure

As the title states, I'm thinking of making a simple-card-game based website, using persistent connection technology (Something like [signalR](http://signalr.net/)) for the actual game part of it.

I've never planned a site to use this technology, and wondering for those who have, are there any additional things that need to be taken into consideration for the site structure?

I'm planning on using the asp MVC framework for the whole thing, and starting off with some simple game (e.g. card based Rock/Paper/Scissors) for proof of concept (to see if I can get it working how I think it would in my head).

Answer (score 1):

You need take into account the browser compatibility issues when working with technologies that do/don't use web-sockets. This is very important point.

Another thing is exploring advantages of [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) library with ASP.NET MVC architecture.